# Error while matchig nested json array in Karate

Tags: karate

Can anybody help me with the below error? I am not sure what I am missing. I guess something very simple I am missing.

> assertion failed: path: $[0].drives[*], actual: [{"partitionData":[{"label":"Recovery"},{"label":""},{"label":"New Volume"},{"label":""}]}], expected: {partitionData=[{"label":"#present"}]}, reason: actual value does not contain expected

Below is my schema code:

```
 * set schema
 | path      | 0           |  
 | drives    | [{"partitionData": [{"label":"#present"}] }] |
```

Below is the output:

```
            [
            {
            "drives": [
              {
                "partitionData": [
                  {
                    "label": "Recovery"
                  },
                  {
                    "label": ""
                  },
                  {
                    "label": "New Volume"
                  },
                  {
                    "label": ""
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
            }
            ]
```

And match each output contains schema[0]

Comment: Done and action taken on other posts @PeterThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is confusing, here is a simple example. Don't use `set` if not needed.

```
* def schema = { "partitionData": [ { "label" : "#present" } ] }
* def response = { drives: [ { "partitionData": [ { "label" : "foo" } ] } ] }
* match each response.drives == schema
```

Comment: In this particular scenario, I am forced to use set because set was used to create a schema of multiple nested JSON and what I posted was just a part of it. Hence while validating through schema(multi nested JSON) formed by set to the response, it failed. However, it does work fine when I store schema in def. But simply due to large schema i am forced to use set.

Comment: Due to change in my project, I lost this test case and hence didn't get chance to follow up. However, I will re-create the scenario and post it again for more clarity and explanation of issue.